# Finding a list of all largest open rectangles in a grid by only examining a list of "open" indices

Tags: arrays, algorithm, actionscript

I have a 2D grid that has some obstacles in it.

```
[x][x][ ]
[ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][x]
```

I want to be able to find all the largest spaces of "open" grid cells.

```
[x][x][ ]       [x][x][ ]
[1][1][ ]       [2][2][2]
[1][1][x]  and  [ ][ ][x]
```

I saw the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530847/finding-the-set-containing-maximum-empty-rectangles-for-all-the-points-in-space/17550377#17550377) which is similar; however, the data I have access to is not a 2D array of values. I have a list of only the open/available indices, and this is stored in a single-dimensional array. Using the above example, my data looks like this:

```
[0,2]
[1,0]
[1,1]
[1,2]
[2,0]
[2,1]
```

I could translate it to a 2-D array, but I don't want to have to loop over all the items again to do that. I have a feeling there is some really simple solution to this, but I can't seem to find it.

Is there a way to find all the largest rectangles by only examining a list of the open indices?

**EDIT** 
I just decided to change the array of open indices into a 2D array representing the entire grid, then use the algorithm I linked to. This works efficiently enough for my initial tests; however, I am interested to read about other possible solutions, should I need to alter my implementation for performance or space concerns.

Comment: Some time ago I solved the same task in the training pages of one of the most famous programming competitions out there. Do you need the solution for that particular task or you have ran into that problem? Will the link to the solution be sufficient for you?

Comment: @yasen This problem is not from any competition or anything, just something I have run into at work. I am working on implementing the solution from the link, but I would be very interested in any other solutions. If you have solved this (or a similar problem), please do post what you found.

Answer (score 0):

Of course.

To find a rectangle:

- Start with any free cell.  Assume this is going to be the upper-left corner.
- See if it can be extended horizontally.
- See if it can be extended vertically.
- Backtrack.

I'll ellaborate on this later, but thought this could give you a jump-start.

Comment: Every "See if it can be extended" requires iterating over the list of the free cells... So, for a square with size M and N free cells it would be something like `O(M*N*N)`, where also `M` ~ `N` - and this is only finding one possibility.

Comment: @BartoszKP  So?  It's an easy, practical, and short algorithm that will run well enough for most `N`s.  Besides, the person seems to be a student who is to devise his/her own algorithm.  Do you think his/her professor is going to get a good impression with something like **that**?  Let's allow the OP to give his/her opinion.  We can also ask for N.  Bet you it's not more than 10 (tops 20).

Comment: So, it's cheaper to convert to 2D array, and use the N*N solution from the link provided by the OP :)

Comment: @BartoszKP  Don't know yet.  I'm working on an idea right now.  It could be O(N*logN).

Answer (score 0):

The list of available coordinates is sorted.

So have a global, upto-now maximum rectangle, as list too.

Do a list walk, and for every item call a function with the sublist starting at the item. To find the largest rectangle starting top-left with that item.

```
public List<Coord> getMaxRectangle(List<Coord> openCoords) {
    List<Coord> currentMaxRectangle = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < openCoords.size(); ++i) {
        // Handle all rectangles starting here:
        currentMaxRectangle = maxRectangleStartingAt(i, currentMaxRectangle);
    }
    return currentMaxRectangle;
}

public List<Coord> maxRectangleStartingAt(int i, List<Coord> openCoords) {
    // Now the interesting part:
    // Take the maximal width list first: standing for all widths 1, ... max width.
    List<Coord> rect = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = i; j < openCoords.size()
            && openCoords.get(j).y == openCoords.get(i).y
            && openCoords.get(j).x - openCoords.get(i).x == j - i;
            ++j) {
        rect.add(openCoords.get(j);
    }
    int maxWidth = rect.size();
    // Now we can look for next lines below rect.get(0), ... get(maxWidth - 1),
    // continuously diminishing maxWidth till 0.
    // When we need to diminish maxWidth, we can look wether the original
    // maxWidth by (currentY - 1) is a maximum result.
    ...
}
```

So we walk:

```
           +-------------+ 1st rect
           |           |
           |           | 2nd rect
           |      | 3rd rect
           |   | 4th rect
```

---

***Demonstration of O(N²) complexity:***

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] openCoords = {
        {0, 2},
        {1, 0},
        {1, 1},
        {1, 2},
        {2, 0},
        {2, 1}
    };
    new MaxRectFinder().find(openCoords);
}

private int[] maximumTopLeft;
private int[] maximumSize;

private void find(int[][] openCoords) {
    maximumTopLeft = null;
    maximumSize = new int[2];
    for (int topLeftCandidateI = 0; topLeftCandidateI < openCoords.length; ++topLeftCandidateI) {
        int yOrig = openCoords[topLeftCandidateI][0];
        int xOrig = openCoords[topLeftCandidateI][1];
        int y = yOrig;
        int x = xOrig + 1;
        int j = topLeftCandidateI + 1;
        while (j < openCoords.length
                && openCoords[j][0] == y
                && openCoords[j][1] == x) {
            ++x;
            ++j;
        }
        // Now we have a maximum x.
        for (;;) {
            // Skip after right side on current line:
            while (j < openCoords.length
                    && openCoords[j][0] == y) {
                ++j;
            }
            ++y;
            // Check for maximum:
            if (maximumTopLeft == null || (y - yOrig)*(x - xOrig) > maximumSize[0] * maximumSize[1]) {
                maximumSize[0] = y - yOrig;
                maximumSize[1] = x - xOrig;
                maximumTopLeft = openCoords[topLeftCandidateI];
            }
            // Skip before left side below origin:
            while (j < openCoords.length
                    && openCoords[j][0] == y
                    && openCoords[j][1] < x) {
                ++j;
            }
            if (j >= openCoords.length
                    || openCoords[j][0] != y
                    || openCoords[j][1] != x) {
                break;
            }
            // Register rectangle part:
            int x2 = xOrig;
            while (j < openCoords.length
                    && openCoords[j][0] == y
                    && openCoords[j][1] == x2
                    && x2 <= x) {
                ++x2;
                ++j;
            }
            x = x2;
        }
    }
    if (maximumTopLeft == null) {
        System.out.println("No solution found, not even 1x1.");
    } else {
        System.out.printf("At [%d, %d] with size [%d, %d].%n",
                maximumTopLeft[0], maximumTopLeft[1], maximumSize[0], maximumSize[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also huge complexity, as the other answer. Still cheaper to convert to 2D array and use the solution from the link given by OP.

Comment: @BartoszKP in fact one needs not maintain a `rect` list, origin, width and height suffice. The complexity is **O(N²)**: for every top-left point scanning the remaining list. I just did not want to spell out the most elegant solution, but leave enough to work out oneself. _Looks like homework._

Comment: I was referring to computational complexity, not memory. The next phase, you described in the comment section of your code requires scanning the `openCoords` list for each row of the desired rectangle, so it makes it `O(N*N*M)` where `M` is the height of this rectangle. I'm not sure, but I fail to see a way to avoid this - any dictionary-like method will be in fact creating a 2D array.

Comment: @BartoszKP as no points received, I now anyway give a full solution (**but with one bug!**). Not so bad, don't you think? As the list contains only open/available coordinates I find it acceptable.

Comment: Looks nice (good idea with the bug :) ). However, it's `O(N*N*M)`: `for (int topLeftCandidateI = 0; topLeftCandidateI < openCoords.length; ++topLeftCandidateI)` gives `N`, `for (;;) {` gives `* M`, and `while` loops inside give another `*N`. You are right that it's N² in terms of free coordinates count only, however it's more than N² in terms of board/rectangle size. I denote the rectangle's height with `M`.

Comment: @BartoszKP thanks & nice finding someone with a critical eye. The for loop, increasing y, in fact interates j to N. It breaks at `j >= openCoords.length` so is N; the inner whiles simply increasing j. Or otherwise formulated: the for-loop walks once further through the list. O(NxN). Your point I think, is that iterating with j goes horizontal and vertical over the board. To keep it simple, I keep the complexity over the input list of coords.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem with complexities when there is more than one variable. I still see 3 loops inside each other, and `M` (from my comment above) is somehow related to `N` (`M` ~ `N` probably). However I can't prove anything, so I'll just take your word for it, for now ;)

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was the simple approach.  This a completely different one.

### Algorithm

1. Identify horizontal runs and transform to rectangle notation.
2. Initialize `currRects` list with rectangles in row 0.
3. Set currRow to 1.
4. For each rectangle `b` in `currRects`, find intersections with horizontal runs `a` in row `currRow`.  An intersect operation `i` is defined as

   ```
       r(axi-axt,ayi-ayt) i r(bxi-bxt,byi-byt)
   ```

   Its relevance is how both rectangle's `y` range intersect.  Depicting it graphically:

   ```
          bbb
       aa|   |     No intersect
       aa|aa |     Partial intersect
       aa|aaa|     a contains b
       aa|aaa|a    a contains b
         |aa |     b contains a
         |aaa|     a equal b
         |aaa|a    a contains b
         | aa|     b contains a
         | aa|a    Partial intersect
         |   |aa   No intersect
   ```

   The necessary logic to determine each case is based in `ayi`, `ayt`, `byi`, and `byt` and simple, thus not described here.

   This function will return a list of up to 2 rectangles and a flag.

   ```
       No intersect       ([],true)
       Partial intersect: ([red,a],true)
       b contains a:      ([red],true)
       a contains b:      ([pres,a],false)
       a equal b:         ([pres],false)
   ```

   `red` and `pres` are the result of combining the previous rectangle `b` with the incoming `a`.  It can be `pres`erving the width (in the sense of y coordinates) of the rectangle, or `red`ucing it, but the difference is not important algorithmically.

   The core of step 4 is to keep a list `nextCurrRects` with all the rectangles returned by function `intersect`.  `nextCurrRects` should be initially empty, of course.  Additionally, if for a rectangle `b` in the previous `currRects` the returned flag is never `false`, then `b` needs to be put in the final resulting list (or just printed or "yielded").
5. Make `currRects` equal to `nextCurrRects`.  Iterate if `currRow` has not reached the end.
6. All rectangles still in `currRects` also belong to the result.

### Example

1) `inRects= [ r(0-0,2-2), r(1-1,0-2), r(2-2,0-1) ]`

2) `currRects= [ r(0-0,2-2) ]`

3) `currRow= 1`

4)

```
    nextCurrRects= []
    r(1-1,0-2) i r(0-0,2-2) {a contains b} == ( [ r(0-1,2-2), r(1-1,0-2)] ], false )
    nextCurrRects == [ r(0-1,2-2), r(1-1,0-2)] ]
```

5) `currRects == [ r(0-1,2-2), r(1-1,0-2)] ]`

4)

```
    nextCurrRects= []

    r(2-2,0-1) i r(0-1,2-2) {No intersect} == ( [], true )
    Never false -> result= [ r(0-1,2-2) ]

    r(2-2,0-1) i r(1-1,0-2) {Partial intersect} == ( r(1-2,0-1), true )
    nextCurrRects= [ r(1-2,0-1) ]
    Never false -> result= [ r(0-1,2-2) , r(1-2,0-1) ]
```

5) `currRects= [ r(1-2,0-1) ]`

6) `result= [ r(0-1,2-2) , r(1-2,0-1) , r(1-2,0-1) ]`

In fact, the algorithm just "discovered" that there is a 3rd resulting rectangle not considered in the original example:

```
    [x][x][3]
    [ ][ ][3]
    [ ][ ][x]
```

### Code

```
class Range:
    def __init__(self,start,end=None):
        self.start= start
        self.end= end if end is not None else start
    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.start > self.end
    def isUnit(self):
        return self.start == self.end
    def intersect(self,other):
        return Range( max(self.start,other.start) , min(self.end,other.end) )
    def contains(self,other):
        return self.start <= other.start and self.end >= other.end 
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Range(%d,%d)" % ( self.start, self.end )

class Rect:
    def __init__(self,xRange,yRange):
        self.xRange= xRange
        self.yRange= yRange
    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.xRange.isEmpty() or self.yRange.isEmpty()
    def isUnit(self):
        return self.xRange.isUnit() and self.yRange.isUnit()
    def intersect(self,other):
        return Range( max(self.start,other.start) , min(self.end,other.end) )
    def contains(self,other):
        return self.xRange.contains(other.xRange) and self.yRange.contains(other.yRange)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Rect(%s,%s)" % ( self.xRange, self.yRange )

def intersect(a,b):
    r= Rect( Range(b.xRange.start,a.xRange.end) , a.yRange.intersect(b.yRange) )
    brokenB= not a.yRange.contains(b.yRange)
    fullyAbsorbedA= b.yRange.contains(a.yRange)
    return (r,brokenB,fullyAbsorbedA)

def findOpenRectangles(freeElements,pastRowNum):        

    #  From `freeElements`, compute free runs into `freeRunsPerRow`
    from collections import defaultdict
    freeRunsPerRow= defaultdict(set)
    rowNum= -1
    currRun= None
    for fe in freeElements :
        if fe[0] != rowNum :
            if currRun is not None:
                freeRunsPerRow[rowNum]|= { Rect(Range(rowNum),currRun) }
            currRun= Range(fe[1],fe[1])
            rowNum= fe[0]
        elif fe[1] == currRun.end + 1 :
            currRun= Range(currRun.start,fe[1])
        else:
            freeRunsPerRow[rowNum]|= { Rect(Range(rowNum),currRun) }
            currRun= Range(fe[1],fe[1])
    if currRun is not None:
        freeRunsPerRow[rowNum]|= { Rect(Range(rowNum),currRun) }
        currRun= None
    for freeRuns in freeRunsPerRow.items() :
        print( freeRuns )

    #  Yield open rectangles
    currRects= set()
    for currRow in range(0,pastRowNum) :
        continuingRects= set()
        startingRects= set( freeRunsPerRow[currRow] )
        for b in currRects :
            brokenB= True
            for a in freeRunsPerRow[currRow] :
                modifiedContinuingRect, t_brokenB, t_absorbedA= intersect(a,b)
                if not modifiedContinuingRect.isEmpty() and not [ x for x in continuingRects if x.contains(modifiedContinuingRect) ] :
                    continuingRects-= { x for x in continuingRects if modifiedContinuingRect.contains(x) }
                    continuingRects|= {modifiedContinuingRect}
                if not t_brokenB : brokenB= False
                if t_absorbedA : startingRects-= {a}
            if brokenB and not b.isUnit() : yield b
        currRects= continuingRects
        currRects|= startingRects
    for b in currRects : 
        if not b.isUnit() : yield b
```

### Test/Example

Using the following test code:

```
input= []
input.append("   X    ")
input.append("        ")
input.append(" X      ")
input.append("     X X")
input.append("        ")
input.append("        ")
input.append("    X   ")
input.append("   X  X ")
input.append(" X     X")

# Translates input into a list of coordinates of free elements
freeElements= []
for rowNum, row in enumerate(input):
    for colNum, element in enumerate(row):
        if element == " " :
            freeElements.append( (rowNum,colNum) )
for fe in freeElements :
    print( fe )

# Find and print open rectangles
for openRect in findOpenRectangles(freeElements,len(input)) :
    print( openRect )
```

Output is the following (some formatting to save space and titles added):

#### freeElements

(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2),         (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7)
(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7)
(2, 0),         (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7)
(3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4),         (3, 6)
(4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7)
(5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), (5, 7)
(6, 0), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3),         (6, 5), (6, 6), (6, 7)
(7, 0), (7, 1), (7, 2),         (7, 4), (7, 5),         (7, 7)
(8, 0),         (8, 2), (8, 3), (8, 4), (8, 5), (8, 6)

#### freeRunsPerRow

(0, {Rect(Range(0,0),Range(0,2)), Rect(Range(0,0),Range(4,7))})
(1, {Rect(Range(1,1),Range(0,7))})
(2, {Rect(Range(2,2),Range(2,7)), Rect(Range(2,2),Range(0,0))})
(3, {Rect(Range(3,3),Range(6,6)), Rect(Range(3,3),Range(0,4))})
(4, {Rect(Range(4,4),Range(0,7))})
(5, {Rect(Range(5,5),Range(0,7))})
(6, {Rect(Range(6,6),Range(5,7)), Rect(Range(6,6),Range(0,3))})
(7, {Rect(Range(7,7),Range(7,7)), Rect(Range(7,7),Range(4,5)), Rect(Range(7,7),Range(0,2))})
(8, {Rect(Range(8,8),Range(0,0)), Rect(Range(8,8),Range(2,6))})

#### findOpenRectangles(freeElements,len(input))

Rect(Range(0,1),Range(0,2))
Rect(Range(1,1),Range(0,7))
Rect(Range(0,2),Range(4,7))
Rect(Range(1,2),Range(2,7))
Rect(Range(3,5),Range(0,4))
Rect(Range(0,5),Range(4,4))
Rect(Range(4,5),Range(0,7))
Rect(Range(1,5),Range(2,4))
Rect(Range(1,6),Range(2,3))
Rect(Range(4,6),Range(5,7))
Rect(Range(0,6),Range(6,6))
Rect(Range(3,6),Range(0,3))
Rect(Range(3,7),Range(0,2))
Rect(Range(4,7),Range(7,7))
Rect(Range(8,8),Range(2,6))
Rect(Range(7,8),Range(4,5))
Rect(Range(0,8),Range(2,2))
Rect(Range(4,8),Range(5,5))
Rect(Range(0,8),Range(0,0))

### Test/Example Conclusion

Output is correct.  All non-trivial rectangles are present.